# Why Debezium creates Topics for all the tables, even when table.whitelist is specified

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium plugin for Kafka Connect to stream MySQL Database changes.

I have explicitly mentioned my **whitelist table** in the

> connector.properties

**table.whitelist=tripDriverMapping**

**database.tables=azuga.tripDriverMapping**

[image]

Why does Debezium create topics for all the tables in the database? Is there any workaround to avoid creation of all these unnecessary topics as I'm going to consume from only one topic.

Comment: Can you post your entire Connector configuration? Also screenshots are not a nice way to share the list of topics, better is simply the output of `kafka-topics --zookeeper <server>:2181 --list`

Comment: This shouldn't actually happen; do you see any messages in the topics for the non-whitelisted tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct configuration for the connector is:

```
database.whitelist=azuga
table.whitelist=azuga.tripDriverMapping
```

`database.whitelist` might be optional